# The clicked button should remain hovered and other buttons should be disabled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My buttons are being created dynamically in the controller of my application, so when one button is clicked, that button should remain in hovered color or any color and other buttons should become disabled, I have tried it then all the buttons become disabled.

Here is my code where buttons are created:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i<data.actions.length; i++) {
                        x= x + "<a ng-disabled='isDisabled' ng-model = 'buttons' class = 'btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-xs btn-rounded pull-right' value ="+$scope.forButtons[i].value+" ng-click = 'submitForButton("+ i +")'>"+$scope.forButtons[i].text+"</a>"
                    }
```

On calling the function submitForButton I have done the following thing:

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;
```

So what should I do so that the clicked button should be in hovered(or any) color and other buttons should be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

All of the buttons become disabled because your have one scope variable `$scope.isDisabled`

It looks like you have an array of the button text in `$scope.forButtons` so could you store an isDisabled boolean value on this array?

In your for loop you can then set the disabled value:

`x= x + "<a ng-disabled='" + $scope.forButtons[i].isDisabled + "' ng-model = ....`

Then in your submitForButton method

```
$scope.submitForButton = function(btnNo) {

  //Disable all buttons other than the submitted 
  for (var c = 0; c < $scope.forButtons.length; ++c) {
     if(c !== btnNo){
        $scope.forButtons[c].isDisabled = true;
    }   
  }

   //further logic...
}
```

You should also look at ng-repeat as this would be better to create your buttons in the view rather than dynamically in the controller.